# Add old commits to Github contribution history with Heroku Github Integration

Tags: git, heroku, github

I am considering adding the Github integration to an existing Heroku app and I am wondering if I [move the commits from the heroku branch to master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238315/git-move-migrate-commits-from-one-branch-to-another), will they appear in my contribution history on my Github profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `new remote say, origin` point to `GitHub`. Then push all `local/master` commits to `origin/master`.

```
$ git remote add origin <github/repo/url>   # add new remote `origin` point to GitHub repo 
$ git checkout master

$ git push origin master                    # push all commits to github/master
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did this from a heroku repo so I had to add the github remote, remove the heroku remote, then push to github.

Comment: Yes. Updated my answer.